# type (string , anyobject) has no subscript member

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization, nsmutableurlrequest

I use dataTaskWithRequest and get json of array with two objects in it (these objects are key,value) and I want check one value of key in two objects.

this is my code :

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")

            var jsonArray: [String:AnyObject]!

            do {
                jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? [String:AnyObject]
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            for json in jsonArray {
                print("object json reciver :",json)

//type (string , anyobject) has no subscript member
                print("state :",json["state"])

            }
        })
```

Comment: What you call jsonArray is not an array, it's a dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

`json` is a variable typed `(String, AnyObject)`. You cannot subscript tuples.

Replace the following:

`print("state :",json["state"])`

with:

`print("\(json.0) : \(json.1)")`

Answer (score -3):

You need to cast jsonArray to NSArray.